# How to get actual height of element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are elements with fixed height. I need to insert new element inside their and update fixed height to new value via browser extension. I can't edit source of elements in order to set auto/% css. Because they rendering by `react-virtualized` out of my control in external site.

How to get actual height after insert child element? In order to update fixed height to actual.

```js
let root = document.querySelector('#root')
let firstChild = root.children[0]
console.log('firstChild height =', firstChild.style.height)
console.log('===')

firstChild.innerHTML = '<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" />'

console.log('Must be 32px')
console.log('style =', firstChild.style.height)
console.log('getBoundingClientRect =', firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().height)
console.log('offsetHeight =', firstChild.offsetHeight)
console.log('clientHeight =', firstChild.clientHeight)
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <br>
  <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: black;"></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image's container has the height set so adding image doesn't change it's height, the image just overflows the div. So it's not obvious what you want to achieve exactly but to get the height taken by the div and all of its children regardless of the children's positions and overflowing you could calculate min of the top and max of the bottom. Also note that you need to wait the image to load:

```js
let root = document.querySelector('#root')
let firstChild = root.children[0]
console.log('firstChild height =', firstChild.style.height)
console.log('===')

firstChild.innerHTML = '<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" />'
firstChild.querySelector('img').onload = () => {
  
  const rects = [...firstChild.children, firstChild].map(elem => elem.getBoundingClientRect());
  const top = Math.min(...rects.map(rect => rect.top));
  const bottom = Math.max(...rects.map(rect => rect.bottom));
  
  console.log(Math.round(bottom - top));
  
};
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <br>
  <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: black;"></div>
<div>
```